# Update Values in One Table where value of one column is not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables like below:

Table Employee1:

```
Emp Id      Name        Department
0001        Jack        Accounts
0002        Peter       Sales
0003        Beck        Sales
0004        Nancy       Marketing
0005        Parker      HR
```

Table Employee2:

```
Emp Id      Name        Department
0001        Jack        HR
0002        Peter       Marketing
0004        Nancy       Sales
0005        Parker      Accounts
```

I would like to have a SQL Server script that will update the table Employee1 to:

```
Emp Id      Name        Department
0001        Jack        HR
0002        Peter       Marketing
0003        Beck        Sales
0004        Nancy       Sales
0005        Parker      Accounts
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `UPDATE` with `JOIN`

```
UPDATE E1
    SET E1.Department = E2.Department
FROM Employee1 E1
INNER JOIN Employee2 E2
    ON E1.[Emp Id] = E2.[Emp Id]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use an update join here:

```
UPDATE a
SET Department = b.Department
FROM Employee1 a
INNER JOIN Employee2 b
    ON a.[Emp Id] = b.[Emp Id]
WHERE
    a.Department <> b.Department
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Update T1
SET T1 = CASE WHEN T1.Department <> T2.Department  
              THEN T2.Department 
              ELSE T1.Department 
          END
FROM Employee1 T1
INNER JOIN Employee2 T2  ON T1.[Emp Id] = T2.[Emp Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `MERGE` SQL command to update lines different and insert new ones int he same command:

```
MERGE INTO Employee1 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING Employee2 AS source
    ON target.[Emp Id] = source.[Emp Id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.Department = source.Department
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Emp Id], Name, Department)
    VALUES (source.[Emp Id], source.Name, source.Department);
```